# force the child div width to match the parent div width

Tags: html, css

I have this following HTML elements.

```
<div id="theparent">
    <div class="thechild">
        <div class="anotherchild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS for those elements.

```
#theparent{width: 90%;}
.thechild{width: 100%; padding: 10px;}
.anotherchild{}
```

Now what I want is that the `.anotherchild` div width must be equal or leveled to the width of the `.theparent` div while keeping the padding of `.thechild` div, how to do that? any suggestions, recommendations and ideas is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There might be a better way to approach this if you explain what you want to do. it is achievable but it might have side effects. So if you explain the situation, there will probably be a better way to set this up

Comment: @Huangism: its clearly stated there, what im trying to achieve is to make the width of .anotherchild div equal to the .theparent div while keeping the padding of .thechild div

Comment: @CodeDemon - is that not what my answer had done?

Comment: @CodeDemon yes but the way the html is setup, you need to make anotherchild position absolute to achieve this which i don't think is ideally what you want in the big picture. Which is why I suggested there might be another way

Comment: @j08691 in your fiddle anotherchild div had the width of thechild though didn't it?

Comment: @Huangism - It had the same width, minus the padding.

Comment: alright guys, thanks for the help, maybe this is just to hard to achieve due to complex structure. I will just restructure those elements to achieve what i want, im sure there is different approach for this

Comment: @CodeDemon if what you wanted is what j08691 had in the answer then you just need to remove width 100% from thechild (http://jsfiddle.net/vbLZM/1/). If it is not what you wanted then consider restructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *.thechild*'s padding is known, you can use the CSS3 [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to add that known value to what ever value 100% may be and fix the offset with a negative margin.

```
.anotherchild{
  margin-left:-10px;
  width:calc(100% + 20px);
}
```

Comment: thanks, though not accurate but still it nearly close to what im trying to achieve, works like charm anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `box-sizing` rule to the child div:

```
.thechild {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vbLZM/)** (border added for visibility)

Comment: I think OP wants anotherchild to equal to the width of the parent

Comment: @Huangism: you got my point, so any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: He said "what I want is that the .anotherchild div width must be equal or leveled to the width of the .theparent div while keeping the padding of .thechild div"

Comment: alright guys, thanks for the help, maybe this is just to hard to achieve due to complex structure. I will just restructure those elements to achieve what i want, im sure there is different approach for this

Comment: @j08691 I was under the impression OP wanted the width of the parent on anotherchild AND thechild keeping the padding. If OP wanted to keep the padding then all he/she should do is to remove the width 100% from thechild. there is no need for box-sizing

Comment: @j08691 in your fiddle anotherchild's width is not equal or leveled to the width of .theparent. Either way the description of the question is not precise enough